# Xcode 7 and Deployment Target 8.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, dylib

when i add pubnub framework in Target -> General ->  embedded Binaries. it's works fine for me as given in below image.

[image]

But embedding the CocoaLumberjack and PubNub binaries (rather than just linking them) causes the build to be rejected by TestFlight throwing a ERROR ITMS-90087. This happens because the binary supports simulator architectures (x86) and is never meant to be embedded/submitted to the app store.

so i removed framework from Target -> General ->  embedded Binaries, Then i get the error

[image]

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/PubNub.framework/PubNub
>     Referenced from: /Users/mymac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/43C64A2B-0661-4986-A903-081EBAD8E761/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/089839A8-D4A4-4343-A277-4E4D028648AB/ParcelPalDriver.app/ParcelPalDriver
>     Reason: image not found

What should i do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way used to `pod` so get dependancy automatic.

Comment: @MansiDobariya Wellcome :)

Comment: If you get solution then don't forgot the accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should strip simulator architecture from PubNub framework.
Here are good article for this topic: 
http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

Answer (score 0):

I think your created framework is not release build of framework.So follow below link to create release build to framework.
https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c#.y3ryid367

Thanks

Comment: Thanks all. let me try.